# What is the precedence of characters when sorting in MySQL, PHP, or just in general?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, windows, linux

**Question:**
Where can I find the precedence of characters when sorting in MySQL, PHP, or just in general on Linux and Windows OS?

**For example**, everybody knows that ***a*** comes before ***b*** when performing an ascending sort on a string in MySQL.  But what about other characters?  Does the dollar-sign ***$*** come before asterisk ******* ?  Does a space come before an exclamation-mark?  etc...

What dictates the sort order? Does it use underlying ascii / UTF-8 values?  Is it different for different technologies?

Technologies to consider:

1. Databases - MySQL / SQL / SQLite / Oracle / etc
2. Programming languages (for string-sorting functions) - PHP / Javascript / ASP.NET / Visual C# / Python / Ruby / Objective C
3. OS (i.e., sorting files by filename) - Windows / Linux / MacOS / iOS / Android

Comment: In dbms it is called "collation"

Comment: It depends on the encoding. Characters that are not letters or digits usually are sorted by their numerical value, which is defined (usually) by the ASCII standard, the Unicode standard, or the ISO-8859-1 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Databases - collations, if no collation is set integer character value
2. Programing languages - locale or integer character value or user defined function (usually all 3 options are available by default)
3. OS - Locale

Answer (score 1):

Characters are represented as mappings from an unsigned integer type to a particular glyph. The particular mapping is defined by the character set.

Thus when you compare characters, you are really comparing the integer that represents the character in a particular charset.

e.g. Java compares `String`s based on their unicode representations. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

In database terms, this is called the collation sequence, and most character sets have a default.  If you are using unicode, you might look here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-24.html

Answer (score 1):

It gets even more interesting when considering other languages.

Ä and ö are letters with accents in Dutch and German, but 'real' letters in the Swedish alphabet (after Z, not between A and B/O and L respectively).